# Work around scope closure in async call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scope

This is a very simplified snippet code to illustrate the problem.

```
var srcs = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];

for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {

    var img = document.createElement("img");

    var tryBrokeClosure = i;

    img.onload = function() {
        console.log(tryBrokeClosure);
    };

    img.src = srcs[i];
}
```

As you probably guessed, I was expecting:

> 0
> 1
> 2

But got:

> 2
> 2
> 2

So my question is: How can I safely pass the `i` variable to an async function without getting altered by the original scope?

**EDITED:**

I have this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/1233788) to a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1233788), but this answer use the creation of a function to break the closure, something that I can't do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img.onload = (function(i) {
  return function() {
    console.log(i);
  }
})(i);
```

or

```
img.onload = function(i) {
  console.log(i);
}.bind(img, i);
```